# Best color to represent a price decrease or sale?

Tags: user-behavior, color, user-expectation

I work for a startup in the world of price tracking across multiple retailers.  There's an internal debate at the company about color choices that represent a price that has dropped on a product.

Our main color is green.

What color would you choose for price drop and why?

Comment: In order to accommodate colour-blind users, ensure that you use an additional design element to distinguish these price variations as well.

Answer (score 2):

On our e-commerce site, we use RED for price drop because red stands out and grabs the user's attention.  Also red is commonly associated with price drop; for example, in US stock, red means price drop and green means price increase.

Also, major e-commerce sites like Amazon and Zappos uses RED to indicate price drop so assume they spend millions on UX and usability, we can trust their judgement.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I think it depends on whether or not a price drop is a good thing.

While under the assumption that a price drop is a good thing (as in the case of a store's products going on sale), perhaps **green** is more appealing to the customer.

On the other hand, **red** could be more appropriate if the action is bad.  Using the example from Chairman Meow, a decrease in stock prices means a loss of money to those who own the stocks.

I'm not sure what the purpose is of your price tracking, but if it is solely to gather and display statistical data, then I would go with **red**.  Since there is no implication of good or bad to viewers, a decrease (in itself) is a negative action.